# Can't return list of docker repository images through API

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub, docker-api

Following the docs at https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/reference/api/docker-io_api/#list-library-repository-images I'm having some problems on returning the list if images to several repositories. Not sure if there's something missing, or is there any problem?

This example works, returns an array of checksum and id objects: https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images

but https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/codacy/codacy-pylint/images returns an empty array

maybe the repo needs some file with info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an out of date api: https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/api/docker-io_api/#list-library-repository-images

I tried to look for the last one without success.

Anyway, this behavior is correct, because in codacy-pylint you dont have multiple Dockefiles, you only have one Dockerfile and you apply tags on them.

For the ubuntu image, There are multiple Dockerfiles involved, that's why this URL returns a lot of stuff.

I assume what you really want is: https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/codacy/codacy-pylint/tags

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to introduce your proyect to the official library. Here you have more information about how to do this:

[Docker-library](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images)

Comment: I don't think this is the case, there are some unofficial images there in which the API works